# SpringBoot 2 http basic security always 401 on chrome but 200 on postman

Tags: google-chrome, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

When sending a request to my spring boot applicaiton with http basic security, I am successful.

companyuser@gmail.com  == Y29tcGFueXVzZXJAZ21haWwuY29tOm0xMjM=

[image]

Here are the logs on the server:

```
15:14:58.359 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /auth/user at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
15:14:58.359 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /auth/user at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
15:14:58.359 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@1b9df029: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@1b9df029: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@44ceb5b9: Username: companyuser@gmail.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: COMPANY_ADMIN,COMPANY_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@380f4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 576768B8D272582DD22DE41579E13BC6; Granted Authorities: COMPANY_ADMIN, COMPANY_USER'
15:14:58.360 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /auth/user at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
15:14:58.360 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /auth/user at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
15:14:58.360 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /auth/user at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
15:14:58.360 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /auth/user' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
15:14:58.360 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /auth/user at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
15:14:58.360 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.w.BasicAuthenticationFilter - Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user 'companyuser@gmail.com'
15:14:58.360 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /auth/user at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
15:14:58.360 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache - saved request doesn't match
15:14:58.360 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /auth/user at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
15:14:58.360 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /auth/user at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
15:14:58.361 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@1b9df029: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@44ceb5b9: Username: companyuser@gmail.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: COMPANY_ADMIN,COMPANY_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@380f4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 576768B8D272582DD22DE41579E13BC6; Granted Authorities: COMPANY_ADMIN, COMPANY_USER'
15:14:58.361 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /auth/user at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
15:14:58.361 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /auth/user at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
15:14:58.361 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /auth/user at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
15:14:58.361 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/auth/user'; against '/securityNone'
15:14:58.361 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /auth/user; Attributes: [authenticated]
15:14:58.361 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@1b9df029: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@44ceb5b9: Username: companyuser@gmail.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: COMPANY_ADMIN,COMPANY_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@380f4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 576768B8D272582DD22DE41579E13BC6; Granted Authorities: COMPANY_ADMIN, COMPANY_USER
15:14:58.361 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@60df6881, returned: 1
15:14:58.361 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorization successful
15:14:58.361 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
15:14:58.361 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /auth/user reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
15:14:58.366 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.writers.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@c0f06f8
15:14:58.369 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
15:14:58.369 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

When I try the same in chrome, I get a 401:

[image]

Here is the logs on the server:

```
15:10:36.205 [http-nio-8082-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /auth/user at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
15:10:36.206 [http-nio-8082-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /auth/user at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
15:10:36.206 [http-nio-8082-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
15:10:36.206 [http-nio-8082-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
15:10:36.206 [http-nio-8082-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /auth/user at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
15:10:36.206 [http-nio-8082-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /auth/user at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
15:10:36.206 [http-nio-8082-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /auth/user at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
15:10:36.206 [http-nio-8082-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'OPTIONS /auth/user' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
15:10:36.206 [http-nio-8082-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /auth/user at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
15:10:36.207 [http-nio-8082-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /auth/user at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
15:10:36.207 [http-nio-8082-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache - saved request doesn't match
15:10:36.207 [http-nio-8082-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /auth/user at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
15:10:36.207 [http-nio-8082-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /auth/user at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
15:10:36.207 [http-nio-8082-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@eb36b2ff: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
15:10:36.207 [http-nio-8082-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /auth/user at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
15:10:36.207 [http-nio-8082-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /auth/user at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
15:10:36.208 [http-nio-8082-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /auth/user at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
15:10:36.208 [http-nio-8082-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/auth/user'; against '/securityNone'
15:10:36.208 [http-nio-8082-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /auth/user; Attributes: [authenticated]
15:10:36.208 [http-nio-8082-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@eb36b2ff: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
15:10:36.208 [http-nio-8082-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@60df6881, returned: -1
15:10:36.214 [http-nio-8082-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

This is my configuration:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/securityNone").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(appAuthenticationEntryPoint);
    }
```

This is my rest controller:

```
@RestController
public class AuthController
{
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/auth/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Principal user(Principal user)
    {
        return user;
    }
}
```

I do see these errors in chrome:

[image]

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You should enable CORS in the server side

Comment: or better *route* your request through the UI server to the backend...

Comment: Add .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/path/to/allow").permitAll()

Answer (score 1):

I enabled cors:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/securityNone").permitAll()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(appAuthenticationEntryPoint);
    http.cors();
}
```

and it worked. I found this info [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework) 'enable CORS at Spring Security level'